# Is there a way to close all Nebular toastr?

Tags: nebular

I need to close all displayed toasts at once like https://scttcper.github.io/ngx-toastr button Close All Toasts.

I wish to know if there is a way to close all NbToastr at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figured out...

```
const toastRef: NbToastRef = this.toastrService.show(...);
toastRef.close();
```